# What is the opposite of "using"?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking words to describe the status of the Toilet.

- Using: someone is using the toilet.
- ????: no one is using the toilet.

So I think the word shall be `Unused`, but it gives me feel like something is new, have never be used. So I want to know the word for the status of `not using`, or any other word better than `Unused`?

BTW, the words are for the programming purpose.
Like:

```
Toilet.Status = Using
Toilet.Status = Unused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to talk about the status of the toilet and you want to use word “use”, then the expression I would use is “in use”, meaning that the toilet is being used. Then the opposite would be “not in use”.

I’m guessing that you’re looking for one word though. We often say that the restroom (and by extension, the toilet)  is *occupied*. In fact, [when we’re in the restroom and someone knocks, a common response is “occupied!”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/123195/36187) The opposite would be *unoccupied*.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following two cases:

> 1. In use
> 2. Available

Comment: What about `unavailable`?

Answer (score 0):

The words on the toilet door "dial" are:

1. **Vacant** (i.e. available, free, unoccupied)
2. **Engaged** (i.e. unavailable, in use, occupied)